# How to count existing lines and add uncounted to counting list?

Tags: google-sheets

For example I have 5 rows with value "A" and 3 with value "B". I can count them by using `=COUNTIF()` but when a new value is added ("C") I have to add it to counting list manually. How do I make it automatic?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please edit your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of occurrences of different values in column `A2:A`, use `query()`, like this:

`=query(A1:A, "select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A", 1)`

Answer (score -1):

Found solution accidentally, just used `=UNIQUE()`

Comment: This does not answer the question because you cannot count occurrences with `unique()`.